# How to add loadbalancing for http4 component in apache camel. For http4 component code check below

Tags: apache-camel

### For http4 component code check below.

```
rules.getRules().forEach(x->{
            from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:"+rules.getPort()+"/"+x.getFrom()+"??matchOnUriPrefix=true")
            .to("http4://"+x.getTo()+"?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
            System.out.println(“Ieration Route:  ”+x);});
```

### Please check the sample routing below(X value)

```
Ieration Route:  {"RouteRule":{ "from":"posts", "to":"jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/?"}}
Ieration Route:  {"RouteRule":{ "from":"users", "to":"reqres.in/api/users"}}
Ieration Route:  {"RouteRule":{ "from":"countries", "to":"restcountries.eu/rest/v2/"}}
```

Application.yml file

```
routes:
  port: 8088
  route:
    -
      from: posts
      to: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/?
    -
      from: users
      to: reqres.in/api/users
    -
      from: countries
      to: restcountries.eu/rest/v2/
```

Where we can add multiple servers in above scenario? in yml file configuration if yes how we can add that.

Appreciated your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per the camel doc `The Load Balancer Pattern allows you to delegate to one of a number of endpoints using a variety of different load balancing policies`
The **camel-urlrewrite** component will allow you to plugin url rewrite mechanism.

This failover load balancer can be configured in following fashion :

```
from("jetty:http://{host}:{{port}}/{context_1}?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.loadBalance().failover(Exception.class)
.to("jetty:http://{host}:{{port2}}/context_2?bridgeEndpoint=true&urlRewrite=#myRewrite")
.to("jetty:http://{host}:{{port2}}/{other_context}?bridgeEndpoint=true&urlRewrite=#myRewrite");
```

The detailed code can be found here : https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-urlrewrite/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/urlrewrite

*This component requires that your Camel routes starts from a servlet based endpoint such as `Jetty` etc. which your code already have.

Related Camel Doc @ http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html

Comment: In my scenario i'm taking context and server(actual endpoint url) i'm taking from yml file, so how i need to specify for single context more than two or three servers(different servers/same server with different ports), please check Iteration X value above. Appreciated your help